# HTTPとHTTPSにする場合、クライアント、サーバーはどうしたらいいのか

Tags: http, https

HTTPとHTTPSについて、HTTPSだと通信内容が暗号化される…からHTTPより安全。という、ぼんやりとしか理解ができていません。

例えば、クライアント側（HTML5、javascript）で
actionにhttp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:xxxx/～
inputでtype=hidden　で何かしらのデータを指定して
画面を遷移させていた場合、この指定したデータは丸見えとなってしまうという認識でいます。

これをhttpsにすると、指定したデータは暗号化される…ということなのでしょうか？

その場合、クライアント側でactionにhttpsを指定するだけでよいのでしょうか？
サーバー側には何の指定もいらないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> これをhttpsにすると、指定したデータは暗号化される…ということなのでしょうか？

HTTPS は HTTP over SSL/TLS の略で、SSLまたはTLSで暗号化した通信経路の上で、HTTPによる通信を行うプロトコルです。暗号化されるのはフォームの値だけではなく、HTTPプロトコルで送受信される 通信内容がすべて暗号化される感じになります。

> サーバー側には何の指定もいらないのでしょうか？

サーバー側には、SSL/TLSサーバー証明書をインストールして、Webサーバー（ApacheやNginxなど）で 有効化する必要があります。また、https 通信は TCP:443 ポートを使用しますので Firewallなどでポートを遮断している場合は、明示的に通信を許可する必要があると思います。

SSL/TLSサーバー証明書は、ベリサインやセコムなどの認証機関から購入するか、無料のLets Encryptを利用したり、自分自身で証明書を作成する（自己証明書）方法などがあります。

自己証明書はブラウザからアクセスする場合、警告が表示されますので 注意が必要です。

証明書にはいくつかの種類がありますので、証明書機関のウェブサイトなどをご確認頂いて検討されてみてはと、思います。

Comment: take88さま　HTTPプロトコル通信自体が暗号化される、ということ理解できました。サーバー用証明書ファイルをサーバーに置き、有効設定する必要がある、、、ということ、理解は浅いですがわかりました。イメージがわかないのは、暗号化されたデータを復号化するのはその証明書だけで可能ということでしょうか？（質問がへたで申し訳ございません）

Comment: ハイブリット方式と言いまして、クライアントは「共有鍵」を生成し、それをサーバー証明書の公開鍵で暗号化して、クライアントからサーバーに送付します。サーバーは共有鍵を秘密鍵で複合します（公開鍵暗号方式）。これにより両者で「共有鍵」を共有します。それ以降は、共有鍵で暗号化と復号化を行います（共有鍵暗号化方式）。文章だと分かりづらいと思いますが、「SSL ハイブリット方式」などで検索していただけるともっとわかりやすい説明があるかもしれません。